# How to get the last list of list.append(i) iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, append

I use a for iteration to generate a list. But I get more than one list. I want to get the max value of the last list. What do I need to do?

```
list1 = []
for i in range(1,21):
    list1.append(sh600004['high'][i])
    print(list1)
```

I tried 
        `max(list1)`
but I only get the max value of each list. And I tried `list1[-1]`, which gives me the last value of each list. How can I get the max value of the final list?

Here's the output:
[image]

Comment: Why do you print the list every time through the loop?

Comment: You're only building one list; you just keep printing it over and over while you put things in.

Comment: remove the indent for last line. max(list1) should at the same indent level as for. Not sure whether this is what you asked for.

Comment: If I just max(list1), I will get what I need?

Comment: Try `max(sh600004['high'][i] for i in range(1, 21))`

Answer (score 1):

Your sh600004['high'][i] that you are adding to the end of list1 is a number and not a list itself. Therefore at the end of your for loop you will have just 1 list named list1. To get the max of list1 then you need to do max(list1) outside of the for loop. i.e.

```
list1 = []
for i in range(1,21):
    list1.append(sh600004['high'][i])

print max(list1)
```